# Using MIT HRTF Kemar database on MATLAB

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I am a developer and not very familiar with MATLAB unless its about basics. Lately, I read some articles about [Kemar HRTF database](http://sound.media.mit.edu/resources/KEMAR.html) and i would like to test it under MATLAB to get a clear idea what it does, then try to implement an android audio 3D application using hrtf.
I looked everywhere for a good documentation but i couldnt find any ([example](http://ses.library.usyd.edu.au/bitstream/2123/9145/2/3D_Sound_from_HRIR%20Data_MatthewStapleton.pdf))..
I know i should convolve my input stereo signal with the hrtf, but can anyone explain to me what is the meaning of all the files in the database, and which one to use? I ll be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

HRTFs are direction dependant. The database is in polar coordinates, the folders are elevation angle and the files contain the impulse response for a respective azimuth under that elevation angle (for left and right channels respectively).

You need to use the impulse responses that correspond to the direction that the audio is supposed to come from and fold your audio data with that (or use the FFT on both, multiplicate them, then use the IFFT).

Note that that database is very old. It shouldn't be too hard to get data with better angular resolution (10° resolution in elevation is quite bad).

See http://sofacoustics.org/

http://sofacoustics.org/data/database/ari%20%28artificial%29/ in particular. The data from ARI usually has a resolution of 2.5°.

Comment: do you have any suggestions on what database i should use?

Comment: @hanaa I have edited my answer with some hopefully useful links. Note that most of the HRTFs @ sofaacoustics are of actual listeners and will not be of much use to you (since they only work well for that respective listener they were recorded for). Use the artificial head data instead.

Comment: I see what you mean. thank you for the link.  but what matters to me is testing it (so i can discuss it in my report) which i didnt know how to start. besides, the database you suggested has a "sofa" extension; i wouldnt know how to run that.

Comment: Well then test it. The example you listed even contains a full walk through to what you need to do. You will need to tell us what you tried and where exactly you get stuck for us to be able to help you any further.